# chaining events with jquery using .delay

Tags: jquery

I'm trying to get a chain of jQuery events working properly, so presumably I'm doing something wrong.

I'm trying to get a gif image to appear inside a div, stay for a few seconds, then fade out and show a different random image inside a div.

This is complicated slightly by the fact that there are cookies involved, but I seem to have that feature working.

At the moment, the gif image and the random image appear simultaneously, then both fade out at the same time. I can't figure out why this is happening because I'm chaining the events and using .delay in between them.

The js I have is:

```
{
    $(document).ready(function() {
        var images = ['1.gif', '2.gif', '3.gif', '4.gif'];
        var COOKIE_NAME = 'lucykydip_cookie';
        jQuerygo = jQuery.cookie(COOKIE_NAME);
        $("a.start").click(function() {
            $("a.start").hide();
            if (!jQuerygo) {
                $.cookie(COOKIE_NAME, 'ld_cookie');
                $('#luckydip').css("background-image", "url(ajax-loader.gif)").delay(5000).fadeOut("slow").delay(5000).html('<img src="' + images[Math.floor(Math.random() * images.length)] + '" style="width: 82px; height:82px; display: block;" />');

            }

            else {

                $('#luckydip').append('<p>Sorry, our records show that you have already received a voucher code!</p>');
}
```

Be grateful for any help!

Thanks

Answer (score 6):

`.delay()` does only affect animation queues.
The `.html()` command ignores those delays.

So you might use the callback function of `.show()` which is executed after the show animation is done:

http://api.jquery.com/show/

> .show( duration [, callback] )
>
> duration A string or number determining
>   how long the animation will run.
>
> callback A function to call once the
>   animation is complete.

```
.delay(5000)
.show(1, function(){ $(this).html("Hello World"); })
```

Comment: Thanks for that! You've just about got me to where I need to be. I'm now using .show instead and calling the function for.html as you've suggested.

Comment: so @jantimon helped you? Then please, choose his answer as "the best", in order to give him some recognition. That's the best way you can say "thanks" to anybody.

Comment: Thank you! This helped me with a project I'm working on as well.  I didn't realize .delay() only worked on animation queues. Super helpful!